# Laravel auth middleware redirects to localhost even after changing the APP_URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I have deployed my Laravel 8 application on live server and have set up the reverse proxy successfully to access the laravel app from a url like example.com/app/my-app.

Now the problem is, as I have used auth middleware which requests user to log in before he/she can access the app, opening example.com/app/my-app redirects to localhost:8000/login

Which is wrong as it is supposed to redirect to example.com/app/my-app/login

I have:

- set the `'url' => "example.com/app/my-app"` in config/app.php
- ran `php artisan optimize:clear`
- ran `php artisan cache:clear`
- And also stopped the app and ran `php artisan serve` again

Can you please help me? Am I missing something?

Comment: Do not use php artisan serve on 'production'  this is a terribly bad idea as it can only serve one connection at a time

Comment: app_url is ONLY used where there is no http request to get the host from.  You need to setup your site with a web server such as apache or nginx.

Comment: @Snapey can you please point me to the right documentation/tutorial to deploy the app properly on Apache?

Comment: There are loads of guides out there.  Perhaps https://snapshooter.com/learn/guides/how-to-install-laravel-ubuntu

Answer (score -2):

You can use in web.php, if user not auth redirect '/' => '/login'

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
        // Redirect '/' => '/login'
        Route::redirect('/', '/login');
        // Auth routes
        Auth::routes();
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the file inside the `bootstrap/cache` directory.Then run the following command :

```
php artisan cache: clear
php artisan config: clear
php artisan view: clear
php artisan route: clear
php artisan config: cache
php artisan optimize
```

Hope this will fixed your problems.